# How should page and author information be displayed in the sourcecode of html pages?

Tags: html

I'm creating web pages (html) every day, but I would like the pages to have a comment in the source code.

In php you can set something like this

```
/**
* this is the info on the page
* @param x
* @author me
*/
```

Is there a similar standard that is used to set comments in html pages?
I would like to specify at least these options:

- information on the page
- author
- copyright
- datetime

*EDIT: I know how comments are written in html, I only wonder if there is a standard used for this kind of information?*

Comment: Who should be interested in that? If it is worth mentioning, put it in the text of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta Tags.  That will let you supply the appropriate information.  See http://www.submitcorner.com/Guide/Meta/author.shtml for an example of the author.  Whilst not a comment it will convey the information, and is machine readable (if you're happy for the information to be public).

Answer (score 0):

You can have some extra text in the comment tag `<!-- comments -->` which will be display when viewing source code of the html.

You can have some extra information in the head tag `<head> ... </head>` which will be display when viewing source code of the html and properties of the page.

For meta data, please [visit w3c specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4).

Answer (score -1):

Comments are set as below is html. There is no standard for author info, etc.

```
<!-- #comments goes here -->
```

You could have PHP set this via scripting if you wanted to automate it.

Comment: Thank you for the correction about the standards. I was thinking more about standards within the comment block itself.